# Vista o Tabla Temporal que agrupe registros por cantidad

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente estructura

Tabla `Actores ( id, nombre, genero)`

```
1, Al Pacino, Masculino; 
2, Robert de Niro, Masculino; 
3, Uma Thurman, Femenino; 
4, Tom Cruise, Masculino; 
5, Salma Hayek, Femenino; 
6, Brad Pitt, Masculino;
```

Tabla `Peliculas ( id, nombre)`

```
1, El Padrino; 
2, Kill Bill; 
3, Fuego contra Fuego; 
4, Top Gun; 
5, El Club de la Pelea; 
6, Ocean Eleven; 
7, Erase una vez en Hoollywood;
```

A su vez tengo la tabla que relaciona cada película con los actores correspondientes

Tabla `Peliculas_Actores (id_Pelicula, id_Actor)`

```
1, 1;
1, 2;
2, 3;
3, 1;
3, 2;
4, 4;
5, 6;
6, 6;
7, 6
```

Quisiera saber como hacer una vista (o tabla temporal lo que recomienden) que me muestre los nombres de los actores y la cantidad de películas en las que trabajo...

```
Brad Pitt , 3;
Al Pacino , 2;
Robert de Niro , 2 ;
Tom Cruise , 1;
Uma Thurman , 1;
Salma Hayek , 0;
```

Y si se pudiera filtrar por genero mejor.

Estuve tratando con COUNT y GROUP BY pero no logro dar con la solucion, la cual me parece que no es tan complicada, aunque no la encuentro...
(utilizo phpmyadmin)

Desde ya mil gracias cualquier orientación

Edito...

```
SELECT actorNombre 
FROM actores
RIGHT JOIN peliculasActores
ON actores.id = peliculasActores.actorId
```

esto es lo que mejor consigo... me trae los nombres de los actores pero si estan en mas de una pelicula los repite...
Trate de anidar esa consulta en otra...

```
    SELECT COUNT(actorNombre)
FROM (SELECT actorNombre 
    FROM actores
    RIGHT JOIN peliculasActores
    ON actores.id = peliculasActores.actorId)
GROUP BY actorNombre
```

Pero me da error... (cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias) y la verdad no logro dar con el resultado... Entiendo el GROUP BY cuando es en una sola tabla, pero aca me perdi

Answer (score 0):

Ibas bien encaminado hasta el momento de utilizar `GROUP BY`.

Para responder voy a utilizar los nombres de las tablas y campos enunciados en la pregunta y no en tus consultas.

La lógica para armar la consulta podría ser la siguiente:

- Buscamos todos los `Actores`
- Los juntamos con la tabla `Peliculas_Actores` uniendo por el `id_Actor`
- Agrupamos los actores por su `nombre` y contamos cuantas peliculas tienen utilizando la función [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)
- Finalmente ordenamos los actores con mayor cantidad de películas primero.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
  A.nombre AS actorNombre,
  COUNT(PA.id_Pelicula) AS totalPeliculas
FROM Actores AS A
  LEFT JOIN Peliculas_Actores AS PA
    ON PA.id_Actor = A.id
GROUP BY A.nombre
ORDER BY totalPeliculas DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9fSxEGNt1moCRYLhAhhLRc/1)</kbd>